# Org agenda - show items that are in any of a list of categories

Tags: org-agenda, org-super-agenda

I have an org-mode file separated into multiple categories. I know I can create an agenda command that will show only items from one given category, like so:

```lisp
("a" "Category A items" agenda ""
      ((org-agenda-category-filter-preset
        (quote
         ("+a")))))
```

and then only items from category A will show up in the custom agenda view.

How can I configure a custom view so it will show items from two specified categories (e.g. "A" and "B")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do complex matching like this easily using [org-super-agenda](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda).  Install the package with `M-x packages-install org-super-agenda` then load it using

```
(use-package org-super-agenda
  :config
  (org-super-agenda-mode t))
```

Then set the agenda groups to show things in `CATEGORY` A, things in `CATEGORY` B and finally discard anything else:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("a" "Category A or B" agenda ""
              ((org-super-agenda-groups
                '((:category ("A"))
                  (:category ("B"))
                  (:discard (:anything))
                  ))
                )))
```

Comment: org-super-agenda ended up solving my problem. I used a (:category "A" :category "B") merge tasks from both categories into a single agenda

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple filters to a single agenda item by making the type a list of matches.

```
("c" "Category A and B items" ((agenda "" (org-agenda-category-filter-preset
                                       (quote
                                        ("+a"))))
                           (agenda "" (org-agenda-category-filter-preset
                                       (quote
                                        ("+b"))))))
```

Look in the [org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Block-agenda.html#Block-agenda) for more details.

Comment: This creates a multi-block view. I should have mentioned it in the question, but I'm looking for a solution to merge the two categories into one agenda