# Can not filter agenda by more than one category

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Update: The same happens when I run `org-agenda-filter` and enter `+work+home`. The agenda is empty. Entering only `work` or `home` works, also excluding multiple tags with `-work-calendar` works fine.

My custom agenda setting "Work and Home" looks like this `(org-agenda-category-filter-preset '("+work" "+home"))`

But when I call this agenda, it is empty.

Having only one category works though:

```
(org-agenda-category-filter-preset '("+work"))
```

or

```
(org-agenda-category-filter-preset '("+home"))
```

Multiple exclusions work, too:

```
(org-agenda-category-filter-preset '("-home" "-calendar"))
```

What am I missing?

org-version: 9.3, emacs-version 27.1

Comment: Does this help? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47437/21118

Comment: @412p9wej If there is no solution to this in vanilla `org-agenda`, I will give `org-super-agenda` a try. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are looking for: my answer tries to explain why the chosen implementation will not work (and that's *before* you pointed out that neither `org-agenda-filter` nor `org-agenda-category-filter-preset` can hack the general searches I was talking about), but I also added a block agenda setting that *might* be what you are looking for. If it is not, maybe you can edit the question and specify more precisely what you want to do and why the block agenda does not meet your requirements.

Comment: @NickD: Agenda blocks separate the category tasks, whereas just filtering the categories lets you integrate multiple categories in one agenda "time view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for entries that are tagged with *both* tags. Do you have any such entries? It seems more likely that the two categories are mutually exclusive. In that case, you get no results because there are no entries with both tags, and the implied operator is `&` (i.e. AND). The "Matching tags and properties" section of the manual (which you can get to with `C-h i g (org)Matching tags and properties`) says the following:

> A search string can use Boolean operators ‘&’ for AND and ‘|’ for OR. ‘&’ binds more strongly than ‘|’.  Parentheses are currently not
> implemented.  Each element in the search is either a tag, a regular
> expression matching tags, or an expression like ‘PROPERTY OPERATOR
> VALUE’ with a comparison operator, accessing a property value.  Each
> element may be preceded by ‘-’ to select against it, and ‘+’ is
> syntactic sugar for positive selection.  The AND operator ‘&’ is
> optional when ‘+’ or ‘-’ is present.  Here are some examples, using only tags.
>
> ‘+work-boss’
>
> Select headlines tagged ‘work’, but discard those also tagged
> ‘boss’.
>
> ‘work|laptop’
>
> Selects lines tagged ‘work’ or ‘laptop’.

So, if you want to find entries that have *either* tag, then the search should be `+home|+work` or `home|work` as in the second example above.

That works e.g with `m` (`org-tags-list`) from the agenda menu, but it doesn't work with the severely limited forms of search that are implemented by `org-agenda-filter`: this function applies each successive tag as a filter, so it implicitly does an `AND`. Similarly for `org-agenda-category-preset-filter`.

But the OP mentions a custom agenda setting, so I wonder if the question is an X-Y question: if so, it may be that the chosen implementation should be abandoned and a different implementation be substituted in its place.

One possibility is the super-agenda package as mentioned in the comments. But it may be that a custom block agenda would satisfy the OP's requirements, e.g.:

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("H" "Home- and Work-related tasks"
         ((agenda "")
          (tags "home")
          (tags "work")))))
```

as discussed in the "Block agenda" section of the manual, which you can get to with `C-h i g (org)Block agenda`.

Comment: Hi NIck, this makes absolutely sense in theory. I do understand now why the multiple category exclusion does work. Unfortunately neither of the following things work in my settings: `(org-agenda-category-filter-preset '("+home|+work"))`, `(org-agenda-category-filter-preset '("+home"|"+work"))` and also running `org-agenda-filter` and entering `+home|+work` or `home|work` does not show the desired agenda with both categories.

Comment: Yes, sorry - neither of these methods can handle general searches: they seem to only handle single tags. `org-agenda-filter` adds a filter to select or exclude on each iteration, so it implicitly does an `AND` operation. OTOH, `org-tags-view` (`m` in the agenda menu) can handle the general  form.

Comment: I added a block agenda that *might* be what you are looking for.

Comment: Good suggestions! I find peace, knowing, that it's not possible the straightforward way ;-) For now I work around with excluding everything but the categories I need. I may try block agendas and `org-super-agenda` for more sophisticated queries.

Comment: Here's a question about OR in agenda searches that might be closer to what you are looking for: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35920/org-weekly-agenda-filter-tags-with-logical-or - I haven't looked at it closely enough to make sure, but I figured I'd point it out.